# How to combine `async:false` and `beforeSend` in AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-steps

I have an AJAX that need to have `async:false` and `beforeSend` function to work together. I have to enable loading spinner before AJAX call and stop the spinner after AJAX done, But I also set to `async:false` to next the step after AJAX done. I am using [jQuery Step Wizard](http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples#basic)

This is my current script.

```
ajax_success = false;
$.ajax({
    url         : url,                      
    type        : 'POST',
    data        : regist_data,
    cache       : false,
    contentType : false,                        
    processData : false,
    async       : false,
    dataType    : 'JSON',
    beforeSend  : function() {      
                        
                    $("#loading-div").removeAttr("class");
                    $("#loading-div").addClass("overlay overlay-on");
                  }
    })
    .done(function(data){
                    
        $("#loading-div").removeAttr("class");
        $("#loading-div").addClass("overlay overlay-off");
                    
        if(data.insert_status == "success"){
                        
            toastr.success("Your registration is successfully done", 'Congratulations... ');
            ajax_success = true;
                        
        }else{
                        
            toastr.error("Please contact the Administrator", 'Fatal Error... ');
            ajax_success = false;
            return false;
        }
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    
        $("#loading-div").removeAttr("class");
        $("#loading-div").addClass("overlay overlay-off");
                    
        toastr.error(errorThrown, 'Error... ');
        ajax_success = false;
        return false
    });

    if(ajax_success){   //I have put this condition inside AJAX done and outside AJAX call. Still same result 
        
            return true;                            
        }
        else{

            toastr.error("Fail");
            return false;                       
        }
```

If I remove `async:false` the loader is working and the `toastr.success` is executed. But, it not move to the wizard next step.

If I add `async:false` the loader is not working but it move to the next step.

How to make it both working properly? Any help or another approach greatly appreciated

Comment: It is considered a bad practice to set async:false for an xhr request

Comment: so, any idea for my curent issue?